# Unable to detect http url inside webview in android

Tags: android, url, webview, hyperlink

I am detecting web url inside the webview by click on link it should open url outside application.

**My code is below:-**

```
  content=getContentData();
  final String mimeType = "text/html";
  final String encoding = "UTF-8";
  webViewDetails.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webViewDetails.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Getting error :- webpage not available

Thanks in advance....

[image]

[image]

===
**If i use the below code then display like below:-**

```
 SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(content);
 Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
 final String data = Html.toHtml(sp);
 final String mimeType = "text/html";
 final String encoding = "UTF-8";
 webViewDetails.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webViewDetails.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

[image]

Comment: Have you add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file??

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @TomaszGawel, Yes,permission already added.

Comment: @TomaszGawel, i updated my question.have any idea about this.Thanks...

Comment: The problem is in your html string. I tested this with `String content = "This is link http://www.google.com. Just testing if linkify works";` and it works.

Comment: @TomaszGawel , Thanks. You are right. i also tested and works fine other content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using double quote try using single quote in your code,

`<a href='http://basecamp.com'>http://basecamp.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [*`WebViewClient`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) implementation ( [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method) as shown in Below Demo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(0);

    /*
     * Your web view client that listen for your commands.
     */
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());       
    mWebView.loadUrl("<YOUR URL TO LOAD>");

}

/**
 * Your Webview Client.
 * @author ru
 *
 */
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d("WEB_ERROR", "error code:" + errorCode + ":" + description);

        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or "
                        + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    // Method where you(get) load the 'URL' which you have clicked
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        try {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

 }

}
```

I hope this will help you and all! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply,but I have not url just content coming from webservice.so its in the string format.

Comment: This will work with your case as well. Because, as you are saying you are getting response from web service(it means you are getting HTML which you can directly load in your web view). When you successfully load this in your `WebView` & you click on the concern 'URL` that you mentioned above then `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` handle this request.